General formula for calculating the number of Triangles formed using the vertices but not using any side of an N-gon
I encountered a problem in Permutation and Combination : A regular polygon has 20 sides. How many triangles can be drawn by using the vertices, but not using the sides?
I derived the formula :
$$x = \binom{n}{3} - n(n-3)$$
where 'x' is the required number of triangles using some primitive logic of my own.
My logic:
x = (total no of triangles that can be formed using n vertices) - (total number of triangle that share at least one side with n-gon)
total number of triangle that share at least one side with n-gon = $n(n-2) - n$
my resoning for above step is:
n = number of sides; (n-2) = number of triangles formed using at most 2 sides of n-gon when i have chosen 1 side by myself and going clockwise around the n-gon and repeating it for all the n sides; I subtracted n out of n(n-2) triangles because there will be n triangles that would have been counted extra because of adjacent sides/vertices going clockwise.
and hence i derived my formula; i don't trust the logic i have used please can someone give me a better explanation of it or entirely new logic to solve the problem.
Note: $(n(n-3))/2$ is the formula for number of diagonals of n-gon so how does that relate to the $n(n-3)$ term in my formula

Your reasoning and formula are correct for $n \ge 4$, and you have essentially applied the principle of inclusion-exclusion (PIE) to count the triangles that avoid the $n$ properties that the triangle uses side $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

First choose $0$ properties and then all triangles: $\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{3}=\binom{n}{3}$
Next choose $1$ property and then all triangles that use (at least) that side: $\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-2}{1}=n(n-2)$
Finally choose $2$ properties (which must correspond to two adjacent sides) and then the unique triangle that uses both sides: $n\cdot 1=n$

(Note that for $n \ge 4$, no triangle can satisfy more than $2$ properties.)
Applying PIE by adding and subtracting the three terms yields:
$$\binom{n}{3} - n(n-2)+n = \binom{n}{3}-n^2+3n$$
Another approach to obtain the result is to separately count the triangles that use exactly one side or exactly two sides.  Exactly one side: $n(n-4)$.  Exactly two sides: $n$.  Now subtract both:
$$\binom{n}{3}-n(n-4)-n=\binom{n}{3}-n^2+3n$$
See also https://oeis.org/A005581
